# Get property value of generic class

Tags: java

I'm using Java v1.8 and I have the following code:

```
public <T> ApiResponse<T> execute(Call call, Type returnType) throws ApiException {
    try {
        Response response = call.execute();
        T data = handleResponse(response, returnType);

        ApiResponse<T> apiResponse = new ApiResponse<T>(response.code(), response.headers().toMultimap(), data);

        return apiResponse;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ApiException(e);
    }
}
```

So this makes an API call and parses the response according to the `Type returnType`. I know that each API call responds with the parameter in the body `requestId`.

Since I don't know the type of `returnType`, is there any way I can get the property `requestId`. It should be in `data`...

Comment: I don't think this generic method should actually do that - that's why it is generic after all.

Comment: You could use generic constraints, like `<T extends RequestId>` where `RequestId` would be some `interface` defining an accessor for `requestId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a type variable `T`. This type variable has no bounds whatsoever; you declared it as `<T>`, meaning T can be anything. Even Object. In particular, `Object` is the common type that anything T could be must neccessarily be a subtype of, and Object **does not have requestId**. Therefore, you cannot invoke `.getRequestId()` or `.requestId` or whatever you meant with `requestId`. The solution is to **bind** the T: Tell java that T can not just be 'anything', it can only be a type with certain properties. Specifically, tell it that it can only be whatever abstract class or interface which is the supertype of ALL the Api response returntypes that has a `.getRequestId()` method inside: `public <T extends ThatSharedSuperType> ....` is what you want.

There is a second problem here - your generics is just broken. This code makes no sense.

Generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination: The compiler uses it to tie things together. It's not something that 'survives' compilation - that T is just gone afterwards. The compiler uses it for some additional error checking and convenience during compilation and then it is gone. Therefore, any generics you do write must add something useful to the compilation process, otherwise it is misguided and/or just there to make things confusing.

In other words, any type variable **must always be used in at least 2 places** - the point of them is to link things. For example, in this method:

```
public <T> T identity(T in) { return in; }
```

we use the `T` in 2 places: This method is linking the type of the first (and only) parameter to the return type, and is saying that however this method is invoked, it is the same type in both places. That's useful. In your code, T is only used in *one* place: `ApiResponse<T>`. That makes it completely useless.

Whatever you think that `<T>` is doing is (probably) not what it is doing. Because what it is effectively doing here is handwaving away the type system, and you really don't want to do that.

Presumably the `Type returnType` is linked to the returned `ApiResponse` object. Your code is not particularly clear so this is an educated guess, but, presumably `Type returnType` is e.g. `String.class`, and this should then result in this returning an `ApiResponse<String>` object.

That **is not** what this code does. This code will adapt to just disable type checks at compile time. You can write:

```
ApiResponse<Integer> thisMakesNoSense = execute(someCall, String.class);
```

and you do not get the benefit of a compiler error, even though you do want that.

You should not be using `Type` here. You should pretty much never use that unless you're writing annotation processors or reflection libraries (and you generally don't want either).

You have two options here:

- The ApiResponse type is always a simple class. i.e. it's a `TwitterMentions` class or a `NewTweetResponse` or whatnot, and never e.g. a `List<Tweet>` or an `int`. In that case, you can just use `Class<T>` instead of Type: `public <T extends TwitterType> ApiResponse<T> execute(Call call, Class<T> twitterType) {}`. This will [A] guarantee that you can only invoke `execute` with a T that is some subtype of TwitterType, and [B] properly ties the things together: Passing e.g. `TwitterMentions.class` to execute means that it returns a `ApiResponse<TwitterMentions>`, instead of a schroedingers cat response that can be assigned to whatever you want even it makes no sense.
- Alternatively, if ApiResponse can e.g. be a `List<Tweet>`, it should be a super-type-token (you can search the web for 'java super type token', it needs some explanation and many nice tutorials exist), so that you can tie the generics together *and* runtime-retrieve the type, which, presumably, `handleResponse` wants.

For the simpler `Class<T>` based case:

```
public interface TwitterType {
    public String getRequestId();
}

public class TwitterMentions implements TwitterType {
    @Override public String getRequestId() {
      ..
    }

    public List<TwitterMention> getMentions() {
      ..
    }
}

public <T extends TwitterType> ApiResponse<T> execute(Call call, Class<?> returnType) throws ApiException { ... }
```